# Should I include that someone cited my dissertation as part of their master's?

Tags: citations, cv

In my CV is it appropriate to include a master's thesis that cited my dissertation?

If so how would you include this in a CV and how would you title it.
I am excited to include that someone referenced my work.

Comment: _cited my dissertation_ Would you please clarify that it's your PhD dissertation that's cited?

Answer (score 4):

No, individual citations are not typically included in a CV.  Some people might include aggregate statistics such as an h-index.